# How to undeploy a model, or specifically how to get deployed model's id from shell on Vertex AI?

Tags: google-ai-platform

In order to undeploy a model from an endpoint via shell i must specify the `deployed-model-id`
as described in `gcloud ai endpoints undeploy-model`

How do i get this deployed model id?

Answer (score 7):

[image: gcloud ai endpoints describe $ENDPOINT_ID output]

Apparently, to get the deployed model id you need the output of `gcloud ai endpoints describe ENDPOINT_ID`
underlined with pink is the deployed model id (`'id: '`)
underlined with yellow is the actual model id,

To get all `depoly-model-id`s of a model you can do:

`gcloud ai endpoints describe $ENDPOINT_ID --region=$GCP_REGION | grep -A 1 "id:"  | grep -B 1 $MODEL_ID | grep -v $MODEL_ID`

And use it to undeploy a model using:

`gcloud ai endpoints undeploy-model ENDPOINT_ID --deployed-model-id=DEPLOYED_MODEL_ID`

Answer (score 2):

Although the question was related to using it in Shell, I came across this question because I was struggling with finding this field `deployed_model_id` programmatically in Python, this thread has actually helped me a lot. If it may help future people looking for the same thing as me, one can find this attribute in the Endpoint class:

```
aiplatform.Endpoint.gca_resource.deployed_models[0].id
```

If it helps, one small snippet that takes just the first endpoint from a list of endpoints in Vertex AI and prints out its deployed_model_id:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1
# Make sure you have your GCP credentials authenticated on your local
endpoints = aiplatform.Endpoint.list()
print(endpoints[0].gca_resource.deployed_models[0].id
```