# Vertex AI on G Cloud web interface : Unable to test model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

Following the starter tutorial "**Train a Tabular Model**" I get the following error at the step of testing the model with the deployed endpoint. (As you can see in the image).

[image]

The dataset used for training the model is provided by google tutorial at this cloud location :  `cloud-ml-tables-data/bank-marketing.csv`

Error message :

> The prediction did not succeed due to the following error: Deployed
> model xxxxx does not support explanation.

[Official Vertex tutorial (Tabular data)](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/tabular-automl/setup)

[What I belive is the old version of the tutorial (not on vertex) but almost the same](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/quickstart)

Comment: you could try *list* , *describe*  to drill down on endpoints and model-state ( deployed or undeployed) using the cli

gcloud ai endpoints list --region=us-central1
gcloud ai endpoints describe $ENDPT --region=us-central1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622282/how-to-undeploy-a-model-or-specifically-how-to-get-deployed-models-id-from-she

Comment: @BorisD Is it possible to share the article you are following?

Comment: @kiranmathew sure, I have updated the question, links are on the bottom of the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you deploy your model, you should mark the option for `enable feature attributions for this model` in `Explainability options` as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L73as.png). As default the option is not enabled. I know that in the tutorial it is not specified and should be. This is the same error if the model does not have this 'feature attributions' enabled and you run `gcloud ai endpoints explain ENDPOINT_ID`