# Vertex AI : Evaluate and Deploy an AutoML tabular model - Error

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-training

Following the starter tutorial "Train a Tabular Model" I get the following error at the step of testing the model with the deployed endpoint. (As you can see in the image).
[image]

As recommended in question : [Vertex AI on G Cloud web interface : Unable to test model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75427051/vertex-ai-on-g-cloud-web-interface-unable-to-test-model)

I've check Explainability options .
The issue now is that we have an error but we don't know anything about it, no error message.

regards

Comment: Hi @user3542259, Could you try using machine type as `n1-standard-8, 8 vCPUs, 30 GiB memory`   and let me know if this helps you resolve the issue or not ?

Comment: Hello   Dhiraj Singh, you found what was wrong . With n1-standard-8, 8 vCPUs, 30 GiB memory it's OK. thanks

Comment: Hi @user3542259, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated the scenario and faced the similar issue, then I tried with different machine type like `n1-standard-8` and it worked. You can change the machine type to `n1-standard-8, 8 vCPUs, 30 GiB memory` instead of `n1-standard-2` to resolve the error you are facing.